# VCBuild link errors from command line

Tags: build-process, visual-c++, vcbuild

I am using external libraries from my VC Express project. I am trying to automate my build through the command line, but it seems VCBuild does not recognize the additional directories I saved/added for the external library's include and lib directories. Is there a workaround to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sorry to answer my own question. vcbuild doesn't seem to recognize the project's environment settings (include, lib, bin paths). what i did to work around this was:
- copied the vcvars**.bat script from the VC\bin directory (where ** is the target architecture)
- modified the script's paths by adding the include and library paths the project needs
- added a command to build the project using vcbuild:

vcbuild /r /u /platform:** projectname.vcproj Release

then I used that batch file to automate the build process.